# Ruby - How to remove node from a linked list like Array

Tags: ruby, arrays, linked-list

I am using an Array in Ruby as something similar to a linked list.
Thus I have `ary = [1,2,3]`
To insert a node I do `ary.insert(2,99)` resulting in `[1,2,99,3]`

Now the question:
How would I do the opposite?? 
I wish there existed a function `ary.extract(2)` that would return `99` and leave my array in the state `[1,2,3]`

Comment: please consider to accept/comment on answers. It is a good, recommended practice on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`slice` will do the trick:

```
a = [1,2,99,3]
v = a.slice! 2

p v
# => 99

p a
# => [1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

You mean like [delete_at](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-delete_at)?

```
1.9.3p125 :017 > ary = [1,2,3] 
 => [1, 2, 3] 
1.9.3p125 :018 > ary.insert(2,99)
 => [1, 2, 99, 3] 
1.9.3p125 :019 > ary.delete_at(2)
 => 99 
1.9.3p125 :020 > ary
 => [1, 2, 3] 
1.9.3p125 :021 >
```

Or, if you want to go by value instead of index, there's [delete](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-delete):

```
1.9.3p125 :021 > ary = [1,2,3] 
 => [1, 2, 3] 
1.9.3p125 :022 > ary.insert(2,99)
 => [1, 2, 99, 3] 
1.9.3p125 :023 > ary.delete(99)
 => 99 
1.9.3p125 :024 > ary
 => [1, 2, 3]
```

Small gotcha for the second version: It will remove *all* occurrences of the value, in case there are duplicates.